# Issue with Shape of X_all in getListAgeDays Function for BraTS20 Dataset

Tags: python, feature-extraction, data-preprocessing, medical-imaging

I'm currently working on a project involving the `BraTS20` dataset for brain tumor analysis. I'm facing an issue when trying to retrieve the shape of the calculated features in the `getListAgeDays` function.
Here is the code : # create only age: category data

```
# id: age, categories
def getListAgeDays(id_list):
    x_val = []
    y_val = []
    for i in id_list:
        if (i not in age_dict):
            continue
        masks = getMaskSizesForVolume(nib.load(TRAIN_DATASET_PATH + f'BraTS20_Training_{i[-3:]}/BraTS20_Training_{i[-3:]}_seg.nii').get_fdata())
        brain_vol = getBrainSizeForVolume(nib.load(TRAIN_DATASET_PATH + f'BraTS20_Training_{i[-3:]}/BraTS20_Training_{i[-3:]}_t1.nii').get_fdata())
        masks[1] = masks[1]/brain_vol
        masks[2] = masks[2]/brain_vol
        masks[3] = masks[3]/brain_vol
        merged=[age_dict[i],masks[1],masks[2],masks[3]] ## add segments
        x_val.append(merged) 
        if (days_dict[i] < 250):
            y_val.append([1,0,0])
        elif (days_dict[i] >= 250 and days_dict[i] < 450):
            y_val.append([0,1,0])
        else:
            y_val.append([0,0,1])
            
    return np.array(x_val), np.array(y_val)

X_all, y_all = getListAgeDays(train_and_test_ids)

print(f'X_test: {X_all.shape}')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((X_all, y_all), axis=1) , columns = ["age",f"{SEGMENT_CLASSES[1]}",f"{SEGMENT_CLASSES[2]}",f"{SEGMENT_CLASSES[3]}","short","medium","long"])
df.head()
```

The expected output is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFdpX.png)

But the ouput is:

```
 (array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64))
X_test: (0,)
```

Spyder variable explored image is here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQMel.png)

I have verified that the inputs to the function `(train_and_test_ids, age_dict, days_dict, etc.)` are correctly defined and contain data. However, the shape of `X_all` is not as expected.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the shape of X_all is not being correctly calculated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code? I can't figure out error without codes... 
Still, it seems `nib.load(....)` doesn't load anything. check `masks` and `brain_vol` has valid value.

Comment: Just added the code as well.

Comment: perheps `i not in age_dict` is always `True`. so `getListAgeDays` returns empy ndarray. or check  `masks` , `brain_vol` and `merged` have valid data inside loop.

Comment: the data is loaded correctly, then what can be the problem?

Comment: If `X_all` is empty numpy array, an error must be printed from `df = pd.DataFrame(...` 
and I can't understand why ` (array([], dtype=float64), array([], dtype=float64))` printed.
it is like `print((X_all, y_all)) called somewhere...
I have run the same code from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rastislav/mri-brain-tumor-survival-prediction), and everything works well.

Comment: I have added the Variable Explored image of Spyder, which will be helpful for you to find the solution. Can you please address it now?

Comment: Did you try `print(x_val, y_val)` inside for loop? if prints valid values, numpy might be the problem. if prints empty, find where those variables missing. try printing variables like `print(masks)` after `masks = getMaskSizesForVolume(...`.